# Explicitly add Reference to Closure Capture

Tags: swift

This seems to be the reverse problem to all the Swift closure issues I can find!

I am using `NSFilePromiseReceiver` to copy files into my app's storage. I would like to do this with a temporary directory, and I like/often use Ole Begemann's temp directory pattern: https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/temp-file-helper/

So, I would use that like this:

```
    guard let tempDirectory = TemporaryDirectory() else { return }
            
    promise.receivePromisedFiles(atDestination: temporaryDirectory.url, options: [:],
                                 operationQueue: OperationQueue()) { fileURL, error in
...
    }
```

I need the temporary directory object to live for the lifetime of the closure here, but the closure does not need it explicitly.

Is there a way to force the directory to be captured by the closure?

If I add `[tempDirectory]` as a capture list, I get a compiler warning that it is not used, and tests show that it is simply **not** captured. Calling some needless operation on `tempDirectory` in the closure works, but that's horrible.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is: If you use Oles `TemporaryDirectory`, when will you delete it? Until that point in time, you need to keep the strong reference, and after you deleted the directory, you don't need the reference any more.

Comment: You are looking for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime

Comment: @AndreasOetjen TemporaryDirectory creates a directory then deletes it when it does out of scope in deinit().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just capturing what matt said in the comments (in case he's not in the middle of writing a longer answer). You want `withExtendedLifetime`:

```
...       
operationQueue: OperationQueue()) { [tempDirectory] fileURL, error in
    withExtendedLifetime(tempDirectory) { ... }
}
```

This creates a "usage" of `tempDirectory` (so you won't get the warning), and ensures that it is not destroyed before the end of the block.

Comment: Thank you Rob. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm glad this is a recognised issue!